# higher-order function callable in python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, callable

I have the following code which I struggle to understand.
It defines 2 functions and then it assign the the function to h, but what are X and Y?

---

more info
def func_max(f: Callable[[int], int], g: Callable[[int], int])-> Callable[[int], int]:

that takes as parameters the functions f and g as above. It returns the function h(x) that is defined on integers x and the return value of h on an integer x is equal to the maximum of m and n, where m = f(x) and n = g(x).

```
def f(x):
  return x**2
  
def g(x):
  return 5*x

h = max_func(f,g)
X = h(3)
Y = h(6)
```

The exercise is asking to assemble the following in the correct order, which I will try but it does not work, here it goes:

For example I don't understand how small x enters into play now...

````
def max_func(f,g):
  if f(x)> g(x): #For example I don't understand how small x enters into play now...
    return f(x)```
  else:
   return f(x)
def new_function (x:int): -> int
   return new_function
````

Comment: x could be any arbitrary value ? You can probably choose a random one ?

Comment: When you say "The exercise is asking to assemble the following in the correct order", do you mean that your `def max_func(f, g):` code block has its lines in some kind of mixed up order, and the goal of your exercise is to put them into the correct order?

Comment: yes you have to put the code in the correct order, and I have added more info

Answer (score 3):

`max_func` should return a function that takes an argument (`x`), applies it to `f` and `g` and then return the maximal value:

```
def max_func(f, g):
    def mf(x):
        return max(f(x), g(x))
    return mf
```

Comment: you can only use the code I have provided and put in the correct order, but anyway the idea is correct thanks

Comment: I think @Mureinik gives you the answer. Replace `def mf(x):` and `return mf` with the last two lines the exercies provided. Like `new_function(x)` wraps `max( )` function.

Answer (score 1):

High order functional programming can get real weird real quickly. Since this seems to be a homework exercise, I won't give you the straight answer, but consider this:

```py
def make_function_print_arg(f):
  def new_function(x):
    print(f"Calling function with {x}")
    return f(x)
  return new_function
```

This defines a function that modifies the function it gets passed. I can use it like this:

```py
def square(x):
  return x**2

print_and_square = make_function_print_arg(square)
arg = 5
ret = print_and_square(arg) # Prints out "Calling function with 5"
print(f"{arg} squared is {ret}") # Prints out "5 squared is 25"
```

So, `make_function_print_arg` is a function which takes a function `f` as an argument. Within its body, it defines a new function. This new function takes a single argument, prints that argument out, then calls `f` with that single argument. Finally, `make_function_print_arg` returns the new function it just defined.

Later on, we can call `make_function_print_arg` with a function that we've already defined, which returns a new function that's a lot like our old function, but with some modified behaviour.

Now, in your case, you want to define a function which takes two functions as arguments, calls both of them, and returns whichever result is greater. I'm pretty certain that one of the lines you need to unscramble should read, `return g(x)`, so I think either you or your teacher made a typo, but working around that, see if you can use the ideas in `make_function_print_arg` to manage it!

For your own education, you might also want to read about how decorators work, which is quite similar to what you're learning about right now: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling only f(x) in both if and else statement.

You can try:

```
def max_func(f,g):
  if f(x)> g(x): 
    return f(x)
  else:
   return g(x)
def new_function (x:int): -> int
   return new_function
```